# How to delay code kind of like "ping localhost..." except in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, delay, shortcut, timing

Is it possible to run some code in C# , wait a few seconds, then keep going? I know you can use a timer but is there an easier, quicker way? Like in batch you can do:

```
echo Hello
ping localhost -n 10 > nul
echo World
pause > nul
```

So can I do this in C# , and would it work with Winforms or just Console, because I need it for Winforms...
[edit] i need to have only a single method to pause, but the rest of the app still continue. For example if i have a button, click, and 5 seconds later continue the rest of the method that was called. Yet in the meantime, still be able to push other buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begininvoke?

```
new Action(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("Over");
}).BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can call [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx), passing the desired number of milliseconds. Your running code will pause, wait for the number of milliseconds that you passed, and then resume execution. This technique is universal - it would work in winforms or in console applications.

In winforms you should not make a call to `Thread.Sleep` from the UI thread. Instead, you should split your method in two - before the delay and after the delay, spawn a thread with a `Sleep`, and call the second part of your code through `Invoke`.

```
// This is your old method
void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // ... before the delay
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // After the delay
}

// This is your new method
void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // ... before the delay
    new Thread(() => {Thread.Sleep(1000); Invoke(Continuation); }).Start();
}

void Continuation() {
    // After the delay
}
```

Comment: is there a better way, this freezes the entire application. I just need to delay one function, like when someone clicks a button, wait 5 seconds then continue the rest of that method, but they can still push other buttons and stuff?

Comment: @leaf68 Doing delays on the UI thread freezes the application. You shouls spawn a thread and call back your continuation through `Invoke`. Take a look at the program [in this example](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) for an example of how to communicate from a background thread to the UI thread.

Comment: it works, but i wanted to avoid splitting my methods, thats why i didnt want to use timers as well

Comment: You can have Continuation as anonymous method (lambda, even), and it might be nicer to your eye as a seemingly one OnClick method. Having it on an actual single method is impossible by definition, however.